# Does such a key exist

Tags: windows, registry

I'm looking for a registry key that handles which .dll are loaded on startup of a program. Does such a key exist? For example I add the value example.dll. Now every program loads example.dll on startup. For some reason I think this key exists.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you need to know what DLLs a program needs? Why does this need to be a registry key? It is possible to determine what a program uses but that data is available in the exe (or DLL) file, not the registry. I think the registry has a list of DLLs that are shared among multiple programs but other than that there is no need for there to be information like that in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppInit_DLLs` in HKLM is for DLLs that get loaded by every process.

See [AppInit_DLLs in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744762(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: sucks its only available on w7 and server 08 but thanks

Comment: It's available on earlier versions, that doc just describes changes in w7/2k8

Answer (score 0):

You added " Now every program loads example.dll " . It's impossible to add kind of hook. Even if skills worked, antivirus gonna detect it as malware or PUP.

and i am smelling something bad.

Comment: no, nothing bad at all. anyway, if such a key doesn't exist, I have other ways.